# OOP inheritance in PHP

Tags: inheritance, visibility, php

I have some problems with OOP inheritance in PHP. I have 2 class, Animal and Penguin. Penguin extends Animal. My source code like this :

```
class Animal{
  public $type = "animal";

  function dance(){
    echo $this->type." dances!\n";
  }
}
```

and,

```
class Penguin extends Animal {
    private $type = "penguin";
}
```

And, my main code is like this;

```
include('animal.php');
include('private_penguin.php');

$tux = new Penguin();
$tux->type = "linux penguin";
$tux->dance();
```

This is all my code. I read OOP in some tutorial. But there is lik this code, there is a Fatal error: Access level to Penguin::$type must be public. But i have dont. Which one is correct!

in Animal class $type is public, but Penguin class is private;

Can you help me!

Answer (score 3):

private variables cannot be accessed from `outside` the class. e.g.

```
class Penguin {
   function setType() {
      $this->type = 'penguin'; // works
   }
}

$tux->type = 'penguin'; // does not work
```

that's the whole point of having private variables - to prevent "outside" code from messing around with the innards of an object.

Comment: But there is no any error in code. What is reason of this point?!

Comment: yes, there is. you are doing the `$tux->type` assignment, which is attempting to set a private class attribute from outside of the object. hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you will extend or inherit any call in your child class then your parent method or properties will be overrided from child. So in your case your `public $type = "animal";` from animal.php is getting overrided by your child  `private $type = "penguin";`

So your `$this->type` will always have character from penguin class, even in the animal class also(because you have extended animal class in your penguin class). This is very basic phenomena of  object oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if would be if you can go through the [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) in PHP. Simply Private variable not allowed to be accessed you are doing right now. What you can do is to

```
class Penguin extends Animal {
    public $type = "penguin"; // else keep it as public without changing as in the Animal class
}
```

## Else

You can write a method as shown below to access the `private $type` variable.

**Extracted from docs for the ease of reference**

```
class MyClass
{
    public $public = 'Public';
    protected $protected = 'Protected';
    private $private = 'Private';

    function printHello()
    {
        echo $this->public;
        echo $this->protected;
        echo $this->private;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
echo $obj->public; // Works
echo $obj->protected; // Fatal Error
echo $obj->private; // Fatal Error
$obj->printHello(); // Shows Public, Protected and Private
```

Answer (score 0):

your private variable is inside `Penguin` class . So you cant use it outside the scope of this class . Also when you are extending a class . you dont have to include the animal.php on you main page also . you can use it in private_penguin.php only to extend .

So the code for Penguin class should be like this :

```
include('animal.php');   
 class Penguin extends Animal {
        private $type = "penguin";
        function getPrivateData()
        {
            echo $this->type;
        }
    }
```

then you can call it in you main page .

```
include('private_penguin.php');

$tux = new Penguin();
$tux->type = "linux penguin";
$tux->getPrivateData();
```

this will do it with private variable .